# RDP to server from client outside of domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, remote-desktop

In the SQL course I am doing, I am tasked with creating a dc (named DC) with IP address 10.10.10.10, and then setting up the domain contoso.com on this dc.

Then I create a server (named sql-a) with ip address 10.10.10.20, which is then set up to use DC as the DHCP, and so join the contoso.com domain.

Now, I cannot RDP (or ping for that matter) sql-a after it has joined contoso.com. I am using my laptop which ofcourse sits outside of the contoso.com domain.

This sort of makes sense to me as my router is only aware of ip-addresses on the 192.168... range, however sql-a is not in this range.

I assume I have to set some records in DC to configure this? I tried adding my router as the alt DHCP server on sql-a, but this didn't work.

Comment: "Now, I cannot RDP (or ping for that matter) sql-a after it has joined contoso.com" - so are you saying you could before? If your laptop isn't on the same IP address range as the servers and you haven't configured routing  then there's no way for them to communicate. Simple as that. You can, of course, simply add a secondary IP address to the laptop's network card that *is* on the right IP address range for the servers. If/when that's done, you need to look at the firewall issue Simon points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you've managed to join the SQL host to the domain, so that tells me that layer 2 networking is fine - that is, your switch is happily passing 10.x.y.z traffic between the DC and SQL host (without the need to route to your 192.168.x.y network).

The fact that you can't ping now makes me think that the SQL host now has its "domain profile" active in the Windows firewall.  As a quick test, go into the firewall config and disable it.  If ping/rdp now works, add a rule to allow inbound ping/rdp.  Or, as it's just a training course, leave it disabled.

Comment: YES! Disabling the domain firewall did it. Strange that i could rdp into the DC from the beginning without disabling the domain profile...